# MySQL error for join query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Not sure what the error is with the query below?

```
select  r.request_id, rr.request_result_id,r.date_submitted
from request_results rr 
  inner join requests r on rr.request_id = r.request_id 
  where ((rr.file_size IS NULL) or length(rr.results) = 0) 
     and r.date_submitted >= CURDATE() 
order by r.request_id, rr.request_result_id request_results;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'request_results' at line 1

Comment: Remove `request_results` from `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: what is the request_results at the end for?

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm also tells you if there are any syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

replace

ORDER BY r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, **X.request_results**;

in the end by

ORDER BY r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, **r.date_submitted**;

*because the columns specified in ORDER BY clause should be one of the columns selected in the SELECT column list.*

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here

```
order by r.request_id, rr.request_result_id request_results
```

what does 'request_results' refers to here ?

change it to

```
order by r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, r.request_results
```

Comment: `request_results` is the table itself. Should remove it actually.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one comma at the end. Try this one but replace the X with the correct table alias

```
SELECT r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, r.date_submitted
    FROM request_results rr INNER JOIN requests r ON rr.request_id = r.request_id
    WHERE ((rr.file_size IS NULL) or length(rr.results) = 0) and r.date_submitted >= CURDATE()
    ORDER BY r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, X.request_results;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `request_results` from the end, it's a name of a table.

```
select 
    r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, r.date_submitted
from
    request_results rr
        inner join
    requests r ON rr.request_id = r.request_id
where
    ((rr.file_size IS NULL)
        or length(rr.results) = 0)
        and r.date_submitted >= CURDATE()
order by r.request_id , rr.request_result_id;
```

And try to write cleaner, well formatted code (or use auto-format option like the one you have in [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/))

Answer (score 0):

You have the table name added at the end of query for no reason

```
    SELECT r.request_id,
       rr.request_result_id,
       r.date_submitted
FROM   request_results rr
       INNER JOIN requests r
               ON rr.request_id = r.request_id
WHERE  ( ( rr.file_size IS NULL )
          OR Length(rr.results) = 0 )
       AND r.date_submitted >= Curdate()
ORDER  BY r.request_id,
          rr.request_result_id
```

For queries like these, use the SQL formatters if you don't want to mess yourself. the one I use is  http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 0):

In order by you missing a comma
Try this code

```
select  r.request_id, rr.request_result_id,r.date_submitted
from request_results rr 
  inner join requests r on rr.request_id = r.request_id 
  where ((rr.file_size IS NULL) or length(rr.results) = 0) 
     and r.date_submitted >= CURDATE() 
order by r.request_id, rr.request_result_id, r.date_submitted;
```